# How Spark will Store a file of 500GB/1TB Data

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to Spark and I read that Spark stores the data in memory.

Now suppose, I have a machine with 256GB RAM and 72TB Hard Disk.
I want to know, if I load a single file of 500GB/1TB then where will it store the data.

***Query:***

Will it store the data in Disk?

Will it store part data in memory and other half in Disk?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly until and unless use are not using some action there will be no effect on the file as Spark follows lazy evaluation approach.

When you specify the action then spark able to process the file

Spark will create several partitions of file then start processing each partition in memory based on transformation and action

Now suppose partition size is more that the current avalaible memory then spark will try to put as much data or chunk of file in memory and rest put on disk and then process accordingly.

I hope this clears your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Akash

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored on the Disk. Only while processing it pulls the data into the memory.

Comment: Thanks Ani for your response.I still have a doubt how it will load 500GB/1TB data into 256GB memory?

Comment: I don't know about Spark specifically, but you can (and many systems do) handle a lot of data on disk (e.g. more data than available RAM) or SSD. Database systems are a typical example of that case. They are handling disk data in smaller pieces.

Comment: @VineetSalvi It depends. If the data doesn't fit into memory, then part of the data is stored on the disk. When you `cache()` RDD or Dataset, then Spark will try to fit only in memory

Comment: Thanks Basile Starynkevitch and T. Gaweda. @T.Gawęda You mean to say that the data will load partly each time for processing. Eg. For 500GB data data will load 2 times and 4 times for 1TB data.

Comment: @VineetSalvi I'm not 100% sure, will check later and write reference ;)

Comment: @VineetSalvi Yes Data loads in parts (parallelly if possible).
And as @T.Gawęda rightly pointed out its only when you `cache` or `collect` data that the whole data is loaded to the Spark Driver's RAM (If it doesn't fit it crashes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.